# What's the correct verb to be used?

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

would I say: Having a suitable Tone, Pace and Volume is or are integral to ensuring excellent quality over the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If the subject is considered as a unit or a single thing then we use "is".
If it is not considered as a unit or a single thing then we use "are".

In this case use of "having" makes it a single thing.

> Having a suitable Tone, Pace and Volume ...

So "is" should be used here.

Example:

> Having pen and pencil is important.
>
> Pen and pencil are important.